# Getting messages 1-20, 21-40,... from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sybase

I'm trying to build a mailbox where we can group the messages in x.
If you put x to 20 you'll see messages 1-20 on the first page, opening the second page will show message 21-40 etc.

How do I efficiently query this? The best I could come up with is this:

```
select top 20 * 
from tbl_messages
where 
tnr_id not in
(
    select top 40 tnr_id   —20/40/60/80/…
    from tbl_messages
    order by dt_made desc, tnr_id desc
)
order by dt_made desc, tnr_id desc
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Databases used are SQL server, oracle & sybase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, rownum AS rn
        FROM    tbl_messages t
        ORDER BY
                dt_made DESC, tnr_id DESC
        )
WHERE   rn > 40
        AND rownum <= 20
```

In `SQL Server 2005` and above:

```
DECLARE @start INT
DECLARE @pagesize INT
SET @start = 40
SET @pagesize = 20  

SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP (@start + @pagesize)
                t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt_made DESC, tnr_id DESC) AS rn
        FROM    tbl_messages t
        ORDER BY
                dt_made DESC, tnr_id DESC
        ) q
WHERE   rn > @start
```

`ROW_NUMBER` is supported by `Oracle` too, but due to implementation details is a little bit less efficient than `rownum`.

See this article in my blog for performance comparison:

- [**Oracle: ROW_NUMBER vs ROWNUM**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)

**Update:**

If you can tolerate some discrepancies resulted from the concurrent updates, you can remember the last record on the current page of the client side and use it to get the next results faster:

```
SELECT  TOP 20 *
FROM    tbl_messages t
WHERE   dt_made <= @last_dt_made
        AND NOT (dt_made = @last_dt_made AND tnr_id >= @last_tnr_id)
ORDER BY
        dt_made DESC, tnr_id DESC
```

Comment: for the sql server version, the TOP 60 limits the data to display to 60 rows, if you have more data to page through, it can't display it.  You will never be able to page to the data beyond the 60th row.

Comment: @KM: This query selects rows `41` to `60`. To get the next page, you need to adjust both `TOP` and `rn` conditions to `80` and `> 60`, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server, try this:

```
--set up a table to page through:
DECLARE @TestTable  table (TableID int )

INSERT INTO @TestTable (TableID)
SELECT TOP 1000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2

--set page location and size
DECLARE @Start  int
DECLARE @Size   int

SET @Start=40
SET @Size=20

--return data for that page:
SELECT
    *
    FROM (SELECT 
              v.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TableID) AS RowNumber
              FROM  @TestTable  v
         ) dt
    WHERE RowNumber>=@Start AND RowNumber<@Start+@Size
```

output:

```
TableID     RowNumber
----------- --------------------
40          40
41          41
42          42
43          43
44          44
45          45
46          46
47          47
48          48
49          49
50          50
51          51
52          52
53          53
54          54
55          55
56          56
57          57
58          58
59          59

(20 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server - maybe a bit more flexible, lets you specify page number and messages per page

```
DECLARE @pageNumber int, @messagesPerPage int
SET @pageNumber = 3
SET @messagesPerPage = 20

SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [dt_made] DESC, [tnr_id] DESC) AS __RN
          FROM tbl_messages t
       ) iDat
 WHERE __RN BETWEEN (@pageNumber - 1) * @messagesPerPage AND @pageNumber * @messagesPerPage
 ORDER BY dt_made DESC, tnr_id DESC
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.